# Contador em batch

Tags: batch

Estou tentado obter as linha de um arquivo tmp.txt

```
set n=0
echo %n%
for /F "tokens=*" %%l in (tmp) do (
    set d[%n%]=%%l
    set /A n+=1
)
echo %d[14]%
```

mas quando executo:
`'echo %n%' -> '25'` e
`'echo %d[14]%'`

> 'ECHO está desativado.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para obter o total de linhas sem salvar em variável:

- Na linha de comando ou em bat:

```bat
%__AppDir__%\find.exe /c /v "" ^<.\tmp.txt
```

- Para obter o total de linhas e salvar numa variável na linha de comando:

```bat
for /f %i in ('%__AppDir__%\find.exe /c /v "" ^<.\tmp.txt')do set "_linhas=%i"
```

Para obter o total de linhas e salvar numa variável usando um bat:

```bat
for /f %i in ('%__AppDir__%\find.exe /c /v "" ^<.\tmp.txt')do set "_linhas=%i"
```

O Comando basicamente seria:
`Find` (encontrar) +  `/c`ount (contar) + `/v`oid (ignorar/evitar) +  `""` nada +  `"arquivo"`

---

- Para obter para cada linha (mesmo as vazias/em branco) e também salva-las numa variável correspondente, use **[`EnableDelayedExpansion`](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html)**, onde em tempo de execução ser possível obter em atraso, o valor de sua variável numérica para o seu `index[n]` recem incrementado, e substituindo "`%`" por "`!`" ao definir/acessar sua **`%var%`**/ **`!_var!`**...

```bat
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f usebacktokens^=1*delims^=^] %%a in (`
type .\File.txt ^| %__AppDir__%find.exe /n /v "" 
   =;`)do set /a "_n+=1" & >con: call set "_d[%%_n%%]=!_bs!%%b"

:: Acessando todas as linhas salvas em _d[x] :: 
for /l %%l in (1 1 !_n!)do echo\!_d[%%l]! && if %%~l equ !_n! (
     echo\ & echo= Sua linha 14: & echo; "!_d[14]!" & endlocal)
```

---

- Opção em layout *"convencional"*

```bat
@echo off

cd /d "%~dp0"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f usebacktokens^=1*delims^=^] %%a in (`%__AppDir__%find.exe /n /v "" ^<.\File.txt`)do (
     set /a "_n+=1" 
     set "_d[!_n!]=%%b"
    ) 

echo\ !_d[33]!
echo\ !_d[14]!
endlocal
```

---

- Quanto a mensagem:

> `'ECHO está desativado'`

**```bat
> echo /?
Exibe mensagens ou ativa ou desativa o recurso de eco de comando.
 
 ECHO [ON | OFF] 
 ECHO [memssage] 
 
Se usado sem parâmetros, Echo exibe a configuração de eco atual.. .
```**

**1.** Não é uma mensagem de erro, é uma mensagem que retorna o estatus para o comando `echo`, e como a sua variável não recebeu um valor em tempo de execução, o comando `echo %var%` é interpretado pelo `cmd.exe` (interpretador de comandos), literalmente como **`echo`**:

```bat
echo %var_s_valor%
rem :: o mesmo que ::
echo
```

**2.** Para suprimir o texto que informa o estado atual do comando `echo` em execuções de teste, onde pode verificar se a variável recebeu (ou exibe) algum valor corretamente, tente:

```bat
echo. %var%
echo; %var%
echo/ %var%
echo\ %var%
echo= %var%
echo+ %var%
echo( %var%
echo[ %var%
echo: %var%
```

**Obs.:** Quando não há “string” alguma armazenada na variável em tempo de execução, qualquer um dos comandos `echo?` acima lhe retornar uma linha em branco  e não mais a mensagem de **`Status [On|Off]`**, mas tendo algum valor, o caractere não é exibido com a ​variável, apenas as strings...

---

```bat
>set "%d[14]%=" // nada/sem valor/strings
>echo; %d[14]%
[linha em branco]

>set %d[14]%=linha/strings
>echo; %d[14]%
linha/strings
```

- Referencias:
- **[`echo /?`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/echo)**
- **[`echo /? | www.s64.com/en`](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html)**

Answer (score -3):

para contribuir...

### read.bat

```
@echo off

echo >result.txt
echo >info.txt
echo >naocadastrado.txt

for /f "tokens=*" %%s in (new14.txt) do (
    
    echo USUARIO ====== %%s
    dsquery user -name  " %%s"
    dsquery user -name  " %%s" >> info.txt
    echo USUARIO ====== %%s  >result.txt
    dsquery user -name  " %%s" >> result.txt 

    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('find.exe /c /v "" ^<.\result.txt') do (
       
       if %%a EQU 2  echo "USUARIO NORMAL ========"
       if %%a EQU 1  echo "USUARIO NAO CADASTRADO ========"
       if %%a EQU 1  echo %%s>> naocadastrado.txt
       
      )
    
    echo ====================================================================================================== 
  
   )
```